# How to show tooltip for an SVG element that is inside a zoomable SVG rectangle?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I have a "zoomable" SVG rectangle that contains a row of smaller rectangles. I want to show tooltip for these smaller rectangles but because of the following code for the "zoomable" rectangle, I can't hover over the smaller rectangles to show a tooltip:

```
svg.append("rect")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .style("fill", "none")
          .style("pointer-events", "all")
          .call(d3.zoom()
             .scaleExtent([1 / 8, 4])
               .on("zoom", zoomed));
```

How do I perform mouse-over or hover events on smaller rectangles while keeping the zooming behavior intact? Do I need to change the "pointer-events" property?

P.S. : (Zoom is ultimately used to properly see the text inside the smaller rectangles. Hence I decided to put them in a bigger rectangle and perform zoom on everything inside that outer rectangle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The larger rectangle "steals" the events from the smaller. Try attaching the zoom behavior to the SVG instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

function zoomed() {
    g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
}

var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 500);
var g = svg.append("g");

var zoomBehavior = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 8, 4])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoomBehavior);

var largeRect = g.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .style("fill", "#d62728")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

largeRect.append("title")
    .text("large");

var smallRect = g.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", "#1f77b4");

smallRect.append("title")
    .text("small");

</script>
```